# Sending media file from Angular UI to Node then Upload it to GCP from node

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, busybox

I am using Angular and Node.js. When user upload multiple video ( no restriction on size ) or image at a time Then what is the best and optimised way to do it ?

when user upload multiple file using Angular UI, then how i can send these large file to node backend and then uploading these file from node to GCP.

I am using busybox to handle files in node.js side.

I am struggle with sending these large file from Angular UI to Node.js in optimised way

Please Help !!!